# SQL: How to return any Part that occurs more than Once

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query which returns the following error:
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

SELECT Part from Parts Where count(Part) > 1

How could i rewrite it to return the part that appears more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a GROUP BY and HAVING clause like this:

```
SELECT part
FROM Parts
GROUP BY part
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A perfect opportunity for the rarely used HAVING clause:

```
SELECT Part, Count(Part) as PartCount
FROM Parts
GROUP BY Part
HAVING Count(Parts) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`select part from parts group by part having count(part) > 1`